# Couldn't find 'rspec' generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to install RSpec as a gem after having it installed as a plugin.  I've gone ahead and followed the directions found here http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/wikis for the section titled **rspec and rspec-rails gems**.  When I run `ruby script/generate rspec`, I get the error `Couldn't find 'rspec' generator`.  Do only the plugins work?  If so, why do they even offer the gems for rspec and rspec-rails?  I'm running a frozen copy of Rails 2.1.2, and the version of rpsec and rspec-rails I'm using is the newest for today (Nov 7, 2008) 1.1.11.

EDIT Nov 12, 2008
I have both the rspec and rspec-rails gems installed. I've unpacked the gems into the vender/gems folder. Both are version 1.1.11.

Comment: More detail on your setup and what you did, please.

Answer (score 10):

Since RSpec has been become the default testing framework in Rails you no longer need to create spec docs via the rspec generators:

**Rails 2 RSpec generator**

```
 rails generate rspec_model mymodel
```

**Rails 3 RSpec generator**

With RSpec as the default testing framework simply use Rails' own generators. This will construct all of the files you need including the RSpec tests. e.g.

```
  $rails generate model mymodel
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20110531144454_create_mymodels.rb
      create    app/models/mymodel.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create    spec/models/mymodel_spec.rb
```

Comment: So in 3, 'rspec_model' is changed to 'model'. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Actually `rspec_model`has now changed to `rspec:model`. You can use `rails generate`to see all the other generators

Answer (score 8):

Have you installed both rspec and rspec-rails gems?

```
script/generate rspec
```

requires rspec-rails gem to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 3 and rspec 2+
You must make sure you include 'rspec' and rspec-rails' in your Gemfile
Run Bundle Install
then run rails g rspec:install

Comment: This worked for me with rails 4 and rspec 2.13, I was missing rspec-rails.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using rails 2.3 You need to use

ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails.git -r 'refs/tags/1.3.3'

and then

ruby script/generate rspec

Answer (score 1):

Is there supposed to be an 'rspec' generator?  I've only used the following:

```
script/generate rspec_model mymodel
script/generate rspec_controller mycontroller
```

Comment: I'm using script/generate rspec because that's the next step it says in the directions on the site.  I am unable to run this script, or any of my rspec tests with this new version.

Comment: Yes, the rspec generator sets up some boiler plate stuff like spec_helper.rb.

Comment: In rails 3, "rails generate controller mycontroller"

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting nothing generated as I was running script/generate rspec model mymodel.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, it boiled down to the version of RSpec I had not working with the version of Rails I was using.  IIRC it was a 2.1 Rails and the updated RSpec hadn't been released as a gem.  In fact, 1.1.11 is the gem I have, which would be the latest available (ignoring github gems), so I'm pretty sure that's exactly what my problem was.

I've taken to just using the head of master rspec with whatever version of Rails I happen to be on, it seems stable to me (and isn't going to break things in production, unless somehow a test broke with a false positive).

I do it with git using submodules, for example:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec.git vendor/plugins/rspec
git submodule add git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails.git vendor/plugins/rspec_on_rails
```

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 9 (OLPC) I did:

```
$ sudo gem install rspec

$ sudo gem install rspec-rails
```

Those got me to where I could run

```
$ ruby script/generate rspec
```

This worked for me, whereas the git instructions did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using rails 2.3.9. I started of trying to use the gem(s) but just couldn't get the generator for rspec to show up. Then I installed the plugin(s) using the instructions on https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bundler version 1.0.8 you should `$ gem update bundler` to a newer version 1.0.9.

I had the same symptons and updating bundler helped me out.
Now `$ rails g` is using gems defined in the Gemfile. Also I grouped my gems like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'capybara', '0.4.1.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

(Note that test gems are also in the `:development` group.)

Have a nice day :)

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

If you type `script/rails generate`, the only *RSpec* generator you'll actually see is `rspec:install`. That's because *RSpec* is registered with *Rails* as the test framework, so whenever you generate application components like models, controllers, etc, *RSpec* specs are generated instead of `Test::Unit` tests.

Please note that the generators are there to help you get started, but they are no substitute for writing your own examples, and they are only guaranteed to work out of the box for the default scenario (*ActiveRecord* & *Webrat*).

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Answer (score -1):

You might need to run bundle exec :

```
bundle exec rails g rspec:install
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to do

```
sudo gem install cucumber-rails
```